# A way to decompress mp3 frames in managed code to PCM or better ADPCM

Tags: c#, .net, mp3, pcm, adpcm

Is there a way to decompress mp3 frames in managed code to PCM or better ADPCM data without using native code dlls? DllImport and P/Invoke is restricted on platform. I'v checked NAudio and all its decompression classes for mp3 requires windows dlls so i've run out of ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were willing to do a bit of legwork yourself, you could use the NSynth library. It's an API for working with multimedia content that I created a while back and hack on every now and again. I don't have MP3 support implemented (yet) but there's groundwork for a lot of what you'd need.

https://github.com/cathode/nsynth

EDIT: I started this project several years ago because there wasn't any pure-managed library that could decode/encode/filter multimedia. Since then, someone else may have gotten ahead of me.